# Is there an orbital solver or modifier that allows orbiting tolerance?

Tags: mrtk

I'm trying to create an orbiting menu. For that it needs to follow the user around 
but it also needs a follow threshold for the user to interact with every corner of it.

From a design perspective (Hololens, Hololens 2, MR,...) is it a good idea to have  a floating menu?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking a question! It looks like this is actually two questions, one of whichs is a design question ("it is good to have a floating menu") and one of which is and the other of which is technical. It may be good to separate this out into two separate questions, so that this question can be specifically for one question, perhaps the technical question.

Answer (score 0):

Menu design in XR is a complex topic so maybe deserves its own question as suggested by Julia.

In short, we've seen mixed results in our user testing with floating menus. They "work" in the sense that the user can always access the menu even while walking around in experiences that cover large areas.

If your experience is confined to a smaller space, I'd recommend looking into another interaction paradigm, either using a wall, table or floor placed interaction menu.

If you do want to be able to roam freely, a floating menu may be the answer. You can then use a basic tagalong script or configure a solver (body lock) like in this example by Dong Yoon Park (under section Solver System): https://medium.com/@dongyoonpark/open-source-building-blocks-for-windows-mixed-reality-experiences-hololens-mixedrealitytoolkit-28a0a16ebb61